# How Can I prevent a primary key that I have to display to the user from being updated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a `CompanyCode` that is readonly and has to be displayed to the user.  I have no say in preventing this from being the primary key.  How can I prevent the user from updating this field at all on the server-side?

I've tried the following:

```
company.Property(s => s.CompanyCode).IsModified = false;
```

However, this throws an error that the key field can't be modified.  Is there an easy way to prevent the user from changing the key field or telling Entity Framework not to attempt to update this field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always, always, always, update the entity pulled fresh from the database with the posted values, rather than saving the posted version directly to the database. Therefore, all you need to do is pass the id in the URL:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id, CompanyViewModel model)
{
    var company = db.Companies.Find(id);
    if (company == null)
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // map `model` properties to `company` properties
        db.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: And by doing an explicit mapping - `company.Property = model.property`, you can never, ever update the PK on the entity.  You are not telling your code to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, and you must show this `CompanyCode` on the UI, just display the company code using `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CompanyCode)` on your View, instead of `EditorFor` which renders a text box in which case, if you render a textbox, this value would be able to be updated.  Does this make sense

**EDIT**

If you need this to post back to the server, make it `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyCode)` and simply disable this control via JavaScript.

Comment: But I need to be able to post back the Company Code in my model.

Comment: I think you mean `Html.DisplayFor`, not `Html.LabelFor`. That would just display the property name, not it's value.

Comment: Your edit makes things a lot more complicated (bringing in JavaScript).  Simply output the company code where the user needs to see it (`@Model.CompanyCode`) and use a hidden input field so that it is posted back to the server `@Html.HiddenForm(x=>x.CompanyCode)` inside of the `using(Html.BeginForm())`.  As well, JavaScript is very easy to disable for those that really want to modify that property.